# Exception error running VB.NET App from network drive Win7

Tags: vb.net, exception, windows-7

We have a VB.NET applciation that is run from a mapped network drive.  This works fine on all PCs expect those with Windows 7, on those we get the following:

"application generated an exception that cannot be handled" System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled

If the application folder is copied locally and run from there it works fine.

Anyone know a way aroudn this issue?  I assume it is related to Windows 7 netowrk security but not sure how to work around it.

Comment: You can monkey with caspol.exe.  Or deploy .NET 3.5 SP1.  The .NET upgrade is the smart move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, normally you should get this error on *all* PCs, not only on your Win7 PCs. But I guess for your older Windows PCs someone has solved this issue some time ago. Read this article

http://thebackroomtech.com/2009/04/01/using-caspolexe-to-grant-net-applications-rights-to-a-remote-network-share/

how to deal with the problem. Here is an SO post

[.NET Deployment to Network Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587358/net-deployment-to-network-share)

which might help you, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason this error comes up, It is not a good idea to grant applications access to network shares just to run them.

.Net and Click Once makes it very easy to deploy an application to a network share and distribute it to all the client computers to be run from there.

The app can then check for updates whenever it is launched and download any changes.  You get all the ease of deploying to a shared drive without mucking about with code access security policies and potentially leaving a nasty hole in your network security.